# rank of some vector bundles related to Atiyah's bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E$ be a smooth elliptic curve.

Let $I_2$ be the unique (up to isomorphism) non trivial self-extension of $\mathscr O_E$ and let $L$ and $L'$ be degree zero line bundles on E.

I am trying to compute the rank of

> 1. $L\otimes L^{-1}\otimes I_2$
> 2. $I_2^{\otimes 2}$
> 3. $I_2^{\otimes 3}$

For $L\otimes L^{-1}\otimes I_2$, we have the exact sequence $0\to L\otimes L^{-1} \to L\otimes L^{-1}\otimes I_2 \to L\otimes L^{-1} \to 0$, so I think that $h^0(E,L\otimes L^{-1}\otimes I_2) =1$ since $L\otimes L^{-1}\otimes I_2$ can be seen as a point in $\operatorname{Ext}^1(L\otimes L^{-1},L\otimes L^{-1}) = H^1(\operatorname{Hom}(L\otimes L^{-1},L\otimes L^{-1})) $  and $\operatorname{Hom}(L\otimes L^{-1},L\otimes L^{-1})\cong \mathbb{C}$ by stability of $L\otimes L^{-1}$, but I am missing here something to prove it formally.

For the other two bundles, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you want the rank, why are you trying to compute h^0? Surely you’re asking for something else.

Comment: I am really asking  about  the rank of the bundles. If I am not mistaken, from Hartshorne II.5 Example 5.16.2, every quasi-coherent sheaf on an affine scheme is generated by its global sections, so if we work locally on some affine chart, we have that $L,L',I_2$ are all generated by their global sections, which is also the case for $L\otimes L'\otimes I_2$, which gives 1 as an upper bound for the rank locally, then globally we should take the max of all upper bounds, which is again 1. But since it's a non-zero bundle, the rank should be exactly 1.

Comment: I_2 is a rank 2 vector bundle.

Comment: So it means that $L\otimes L' ^{-1}\otimes I_2$ is a rank 2 vector bundle?

Comment: of course, because you’re tensoring by line bundles.

Comment: So do we simply have rank$(I_2^{\otimes 2}) =4$ and rank$ (I_2^{\otimes 3})=8$?